# how do i reorder plotly legend?

Tags: python, plotly

im using plotly.express.

```
temp_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
temp_dataframe['VALUE'] = relevant_dataframe.RESULT.tolist()
temp_dataframe['SITE_NUM'] = relevant_dataframe.SITE_NUM.tolist()
temp_dataframe.sort_values('VALUE', inplace = True)

temp_dataframe['IDX'] = list(range(len(temp_dataframe)))

fig=px.line(temp_dataframe, x = 'VALUE', y = 'IDX', color='SITE_NUM')
fig.update_layout(
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = (len(d)-1) * p/100,
        ticktext = p
    )
)
fig.show()
```

my plot requires the 'VALUES' column to be sorted and plotted according to it, which then results in another column 'SITE_NUM' to be arranged seemingly randomly. but i need the legend to be in increasing order based on 'SITE_NUM' column, while not changing the shape of the graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eByif.png)

most google searches and stackoverflow replies seem to imply that i have to sort the 'SITE_NUM', but this screws up the main shape of the plot. is there a way to simply reorder the final legend after plotting?

Some data: (first column is not labelled)

```
    VALUE   SITE_NUM    IDX
1171 321874.031250  0   1355
486 239604.937500   0   256
169 275894.156250   1   1230
1188 252101.953125  1   565
446 230880.828125   2   114
827 271964.843750   2   1145
745 272814.093750   3   1167
358 272098.781250   3   1149
419 275497.187500   4   1223
932 275310.375000   4   1217
```

Comment: Pls provide some sample data of `temp_dataframe` in text format

Comment: sorry, how do i do that? should i copy paste some rows and post it as a comment?

Comment: You can click EDIT below your question and add a few rows of data (enough to show different values for legend) somewhere towards the bottom of the text box and click save

Comment: just added some data, sorry its not formatted nicely... i tried :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Plotly Express lays out legend items in the order in which values appear in the underlying data. Every Plotly Express function also includes a category_orders keyword argument which can be used to control the order in which categorical axes are drawn, but beyond that can also control the order in which legend items appear, and the order in which facets are laid out.

So you can try,

```
fig=px.line(temp_dataframe, x='VALUE', y='IDX', color='SITE_NUM', category_orders={"SITE_NUM": ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']})
```

where category_orders you like.

If you want to reversed it:

```
fig.update_layout(legend_traceorder="reversed")
```

More details can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/legend/)

Comment: ive just tried this, no change to the order of legend, only the color of line plot changed

Comment: your SITE_NUM datatype is string or number? you can try category_orders with number.

Comment: yes! it is number, it works now. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Using your code and your data, when I updated the px.line() as below, the order worked correctly. Please check if this is what you need...

```
fig=px.line(temp_dataframe, x = 'VALUE', y = 'IDX', color='SITE_NUM', category_orders={'SITE_NUM':[0,1,2,3,4]})
```

[image]

Comment: yes! the category_orders keyword solved this for me, thank you!!